# convert a 960 grid based site to responsive

Tags: web, responsive-design, media-queries

the website i designed (www.aim.ca) is using nathan smith's 960 grid. i wanted to convert the site to responsive and so i've looked into the 996 grid (responsive) system. http://996grid.com/

in the process of implementing the css scripts and javascript, i had encountered some setbacks... this is actually my first time using a responsive grid system.

my questions are:
- should i also modify the div classes and ids of my separate stylesheet to be responsive as well?

- when i resize the browser, the elements are out of proportion, i also see random numbers that i think was generated from the js like "389" and so on
- can i modify the 960.css itself using media queries? how hard would this be?
- what is the best way to convert a 960 grid based site to a responsive layout?

your thoughts are greatly appreciated! thank you in advance.

Comment: Most likely you will need to modify your current css since it was not designed to be responsive. It's a lot of work doing responsive website, I think converting one might be more work than creating one from scratch. Unless you build the current site so at least you have full insight. Never used 996grid, we created our own frame work using LESS and media queries

Comment: BTW, are you talking about the LESS dynamic stylesheet (http://lesscss.org) or less framework (http://lessframework.com/)?

Comment: just lesscss, we created our own framework

Answer (score 3):

there are a few websites out there that for the most part solve it for you:

First, add a [meta viewport tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to your head of your html file/template:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

best one for 960 grid responsiveness is [this github project](https://github.com/tylerwolff/960-Responsive-Grid)

Just add this css file below your original 960 css fyle (I had to replace the `_` with `-`):

```
/*
* 960 Responsive Grid
* Copyright 2012, Tyler Wolff
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/10/2012
*/

/* Tablet Portrait width to 960px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {

  body {
    min-width: 768px;
  }

  .container_12,
  .container_16 {
    width: 768px;
  }

  .container_12 .grid_1  { width: 44px; }
  .container_12 .grid_2  { width: 108px; }
  .container_12 .grid_3  { width: 172px; }
  .container_12 .grid_4  { width: 236px; }
  .container_12 .grid_5  { width: 300px; }
  .container_12 .grid_6  { width: 364px; }
  .container_12 .grid_7  { width: 428px; }
  .container_12 .grid_8  { width: 492px; }
  .container_12 .grid_9  { width: 556px; }
  .container_12 .grid_10 { width: 620px; }
  .container_12 .grid_11 { width: 684px; }
  .container_12 .grid_12 { width: 748px; }

  .container_16 .grid_1  { width: 28px; }
  .container_16 .grid_2  { width: 76px; }
  .container_16 .grid_3  { width: 124px; }
  .container_16 .grid_4  { width: 172px; }
  .container_16 .grid_5  { width: 220px; }
  .container_16 .grid_6  { width: 268px; }
  .container_16 .grid_7  { width: 316px; }
  .container_16 .grid_8  { width: 364px; }
  .container_16 .grid_9  { width: 412px; }
  .container_16 .grid_10 { width: 460px; }
  .container_16 .grid_11 { width: 508px; }
  .container_16 .grid_12 { width: 556px; }
  .container_16 .grid_13 { width: 604px; }
  .container_16 .grid_14 { width: 652px; }
  .container_16 .grid_15 { width: 700px; }
  .container_16 .grid_16 { width: 748px; }

  .container_12 .prefix_1  { padding-left: 64px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_2  { padding-left: 128px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_3  { padding-left: 192px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_4  { padding-left: 256px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_5  { padding-left: 320px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_6  { padding-left: 384px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_7  { padding-left: 448px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_8  { padding-left: 512px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_9  { padding-left: 576px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_10 { padding-left: 640px; }
  .container_12 .prefix_11 { padding-left: 704px; }

  .container_16 .prefix_1  { padding-left: 48px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_2  { padding-left: 96px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_3  { padding-left: 144px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_4  { padding-left: 192px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_5  { padding-left: 240px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_6  { padding-left: 288px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_7  { padding-left: 336px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_8  { padding-left: 384px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_9  { padding-left: 432px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_10 { padding-left: 480px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_11 { padding-left: 528px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_12 { padding-left: 576px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_13 { padding-left: 624px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_14 { padding-left: 672px; }
  .container_16 .prefix_15 { padding-left: 720px; }

  .container_12 .suffix_1  { padding-right: 64px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_2  { padding-right: 128px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_3  { padding-right: 192px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_4  { padding-right: 256px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_5  { padding-right: 320px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_6  { padding-right: 384px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_7  { padding-right: 448px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_8  { padding-right: 512px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_9  { padding-right: 576px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_10 { padding-right: 640px; }
  .container_12 .suffix_11 { padding-right: 704px; }

  .container_16 .suffix_1  { padding-right: 48px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_2  { padding-right: 96px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_3  { padding-right: 144px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_4  { padding-right: 192px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_5  { padding-right: 240px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_6  { padding-right: 288px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_7  { padding-right: 336px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_8  { padding-right: 384px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_9  { padding-right: 432px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_10 { padding-right: 480px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_11 { padding-right: 528px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_12 { padding-right: 576px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_13 { padding-right: 624px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_14 { padding-right: 672px; }
  .container_16 .suffix_15 { padding-right: 720px; }

  .container_12 .push_1  { left: 64px; }
  .container_12 .push_2  { left: 128px; }
  .container_12 .push_3  { left: 192px; }
  .container_12 .push_4  { left: 256px; }
  .container_12 .push_5  { left: 320px; }
  .container_12 .push_6  { left: 384px; }
  .container_12 .push_7  { left: 448px; }
  .container_12 .push_8  { left: 512px; }
  .container_12 .push_9  { left: 576px; }
  .container_12 .push_10 { left: 640px; }
  .container_12 .push_11 { left: 704px; }

  .container_16 .push_1  { left: 48px; }
  .container_16 .push_2  { left: 96px; }
  .container_16 .push_3  { left: 144px; }
  .container_16 .push_4  { left: 192px; }
  .container_16 .push_5  { left: 240px; }
  .container_16 .push_6  { left: 288px; }
  .container_16 .push_7  { left: 336px; }
  .container_16 .push_8  { left: 384px; }
  .container_16 .push_9  { left: 432px; }
  .container_16 .push_10 { left: 480px; }
  .container_16 .push_11 { left: 528px; }
  .container_16 .push_12 { left: 576px; }
  .container_16 .push_13 { left: 624px; }
  .container_16 .push_14 { left: 672px; }
  .container_16 .push_15 { left: 720px; }

  .container_12 .pull_1  { left: -64px; }
  .container_12 .pull_2  { left: -128px; }
  .container_12 .pull_3  { left: -192px; }
  .container_12 .pull_4  { left: -256px; }
  .container_12 .pull_5  { left: -320px; }
  .container_12 .pull_6  { left: -384px; }
  .container_12 .pull_7  { left: -448px; }
  .container_12 .pull_8  { left: -512px; }
  .container_12 .pull_9  { left: -576px; }
  .container_12 .pull_10 { left: -640px; }
  .container_12 .pull_11 { left: -704px; }

  .container_16 .pull_1  { left: -48px; }
  .container_16 .pull_2  { left: -96px; }
  .container_16 .pull_3  { left: -144px; }
  .container_16 .pull_4  { left: -192px; }
  .container_16 .pull_5  { left: -240px; }
  .container_16 .pull_6  { left: -288px; }
  .container_16 .pull_7  { left: -336px; }
  .container_16 .pull_8  { left: -384px; }
  .container_16 .pull_9  { left: -432px; }
  .container_16 .pull_10 { left: -480px; }
  .container_16 .pull_11 { left: -528px; }
  .container_16 .pull_12 { left: -576px; }
  .container_16 .pull_13 { left: -624px; }
  .container_16 .pull_14 { left: -672px; }
  .container_16 .pull_15 { left: -720px; }

}

/* All Mobile Widths */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  body {
    min-width: 300px;
  }

  .container_12,
  .container_16 {
    width: 300px;
  }

  .container_12 .grid_1,
  .container_16 .grid_1,
  .container_12 .grid_2,
  .container_16 .grid_2,
  .container_12 .grid_3,
  .container_16 .grid_3,
  .container_12 .grid_4,
  .container_16 .grid_4,
  .container_12 .grid_5,
  .container_16 .grid_5,
  .container_12 .grid_6,
  .container_16 .grid_6,
  .container_12 .grid_7,
  .container_16 .grid_7,
  .container_12 .grid_8,
  .container_16 .grid_8,
  .container_12 .grid_9,
  .container_16 .grid_9,
  .container_12 .grid_10,
  .container_16 .grid_10,
  .container_12 .grid_11,
  .container_16 .grid_11,
  .container_12 .grid_12,
  .container_16 .grid_12,
  .container_12 .grid_13,
  .container_16 .grid_13,
  .container_12 .grid_14,
  .container_16 .grid_14,
  .container_12 .grid_15,
  .container_16 .grid_15,
  .container_12 .grid_16,
  .container_16 .grid_16 {
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .container_12 .prefix_1,
  .container_16 .prefix_1,
  .container_12 .prefix_2,
  .container_16 .prefix_2,
  .container_12 .prefix_3,
  .container_16 .prefix_3,
  .container_12 .prefix_4,
  .container_16 .prefix_4,
  .container_12 .prefix_5,
  .container_16 .prefix_5,
  .container_12 .prefix_6,
  .container_16 .prefix_6,
  .container_12 .prefix_7,
  .container_16 .prefix_7,
  .container_12 .prefix_8,
  .container_16 .prefix_8,
  .container_12 .prefix_9,
  .container_16 .prefix_9,
  .container_12 .prefix_10,
  .container_16 .prefix_10,
  .container_12 .prefix_11,
  .container_16 .prefix_11,
  .container_12 .prefix_12,
  .container_16 .prefix_12,
  .container_12 .prefix_13,
  .container_16 .prefix_13,
  .container_12 .prefix_14,
  .container_16 .prefix_14,
  .container_12 .prefix_15,
  .container_16 .prefix_15 {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  .container_12 .suffix_1,
  .container_16 .suffix_1,
  .container_12 .suffix_2,
  .container_16 .suffix_2,
  .container_12 .suffix_3,
  .container_16 .suffix_3,
  .container_12 .suffix_4,
  .container_16 .suffix_4,
  .container_12 .suffix_5,
  .container_16 .suffix_5,
  .container_12 .suffix_6,
  .container_16 .suffix_6,
  .container_12 .suffix_7,
  .container_16 .suffix_7,
  .container_12 .suffix_8,
  .container_16 .suffix_8,
  .container_12 .suffix_9,
  .container_16 .suffix_9,
  .container_12 .suffix_10,
  .container_16 .suffix_10,
  .container_12 .suffix_11,
  .container_16 .suffix_11,
  .container_12 .suffix_12,
  .container_16 .suffix_12,
  .container_12 .suffix_13,
  .container_16 .suffix_13,
  .container_12 .suffix_14,
  .container_16 .suffix_14,
  .container_12 .suffix_15,
  .container_16 .suffix_15 {
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .container_12 .push_1,
  .container_16 .push_1,
  .container_12 .push_2,
  .container_16 .push_2,
  .container_12 .push_3,
  .container_16 .push_3,
  .container_12 .push_4,
  .container_16 .push_4,
  .container_12 .push_5,
  .container_16 .push_5,
  .container_12 .push_6,
  .container_16 .push_6,
  .container_12 .push_7,
  .container_16 .push_7,
  .container_12 .push_8,
  .container_16 .push_8,
  .container_12 .push_9,
  .container_16 .push_9,
  .container_12 .push_10,
  .container_16 .push_10,
  .container_12 .push_11,
  .container_16 .push_11,
  .container_12 .push_12,
  .container_16 .push_12,
  .container_12 .push_13,
  .container_16 .push_13,
  .container_12 .push_14,
  .container_16 .push_14,
  .container_12 .push_15,
  .container_16 .push_15,
  .container_12 .pull_1,
  .container_16 .pull_1,
  .container_12 .pull_2,
  .container_16 .pull_2,
  .container_12 .pull_3,
  .container_16 .pull_3,
  .container_12 .pull_4,
  .container_16 .pull_4,
  .container_12 .pull_5,
  .container_16 .pull_5,
  .container_12 .pull_6,
  .container_16 .pull_6,
  .container_12 .pull_7,
  .container_16 .pull_7,
  .container_12 .pull_8,
  .container_16 .pull_8,
  .container_12 .pull_9,
  .container_16 .pull_9,
  .container_12 .pull_10,
  .container_16 .pull_10,
  .container_12 .pull_11,
  .container_16 .pull_11,
  .container_12 .pull_12,
  .container_16 .pull_12,
  .container_12 .pull_13,
  .container_16 .pull_13,
  .container_12 .pull_14,
  .container_16 .pull_14,
  .container_12 .pull_15,
  .container_16 .pull_15 {
    left: 0;
  }

}

/* Mobile Landscape Width to Tablet Portrait Width */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  body {
    min-width: 480px;
  }

  .container_12,
  .container_16 {
    width: 420px;
  }

  .container_12 .grid_1,
  .container_16 .grid_1,
  .container_12 .grid_2,
  .container_16 .grid_2,
  .container_12 .grid_3,
  .container_16 .grid_3,
  .container_12 .grid_4,
  .container_16 .grid_4,
  .container_12 .grid_5,
  .container_16 .grid_5,
  .container_12 .grid_6,
  .container_16 .grid_6,
  .container_12 .grid_7,
  .container_16 .grid_7,
  .container_12 .grid_8,
  .container_16 .grid_8,
  .container_12 .grid_9,
  .container_16 .grid_9,
  .container_12 .grid_10,
  .container_16 .grid_10,
  .container_12 .grid_11,
  .container_16 .grid_11,
  .container_12 .grid_12,
  .container_16 .grid_12,
  .container_12 .grid_13,
  .container_16 .grid_13,
  .container_12 .grid_14,
  .container_16 .grid_14,
  .container_12 .grid_15,
  .container_16 .grid_15,
  .container_12 .grid_16,
  .container_16 .grid_16 {
    margin: 0;
    width: 420px;
  }

}
```

Or another one: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-responsive-design-using-960-grid/

or guide you through it:
http://www.premiumdw.com/2013/02/12/convert-a-960-grid-website-to-a-responsive-design/